# after debian stretch install (RC3), apt signature issue(s)

Tags: debian, installation, gnupg, apt

For what it is worth, I've just re-installed stretch and the problem is gone.
Perhaps I just did something thumb-fingered...

---

Earlier this week (april 17) I installed debian stretch on my desktop computer, using the Debian Installer Stretch RC3 release, found here:
https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/

The system is now in place and works fine, with this caveat:
When I do apt-get update, I get the following output

```
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease [186 kB]
Ign:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Fetched 186 kB in 0s (410 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

(My /etc/apt/sources.list just contains

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free
```

)

Of course, this is "just" a warning - I can still do update/upgrade/dist-upgrade via apt-get; I get the above complaint, but it still works.

I first noticed the/a problem when I tried to do the following:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

I get the output:

```
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

(For what it is worth, I tried adding other signatures in this way, and didn't succeed -- same error. And I saving the result of the wget to a file, and calling apt-get key with file name as argument -- same error, again.)

Anyhow, I don't recall getting the warning from "apt-get update" *until after* doing the above command attempting to install a signing key.  Now it happens consistently.

I searched and read a fair amount about this; I think for a while I believed it was related to the following [reddit-debian-discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/5mf4ps/can_anyone_help_with_this_warning/). I'm pretty sure at some point I had a report that the _apt user couldn't read the keyring. Thus, I *may have* changed the permissions of file "trusted.gpg" here in /etc/apt:

```
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 17 14:31 apt.conf.d
  -rw-r--r--   1 root root  104 Apr 17 13:04 listchanges.conf
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr  1 15:39 preferences.d
  -rw-r--r--   1 root root  142 Apr 19 12:05 sources.list
  -rw-r--r--   1 root root  126 Apr 18 15:44 sources.list~
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 18 15:44 sources.list.d
  -rw-r--r--   1 root root  193 Apr 18 15:44 sources.list.save
  -rw-------   1 root root 1.2K Apr 18 14:56 trustdb.gpg
  -rw-r--r--   1 root root   32 Apr 18 11:16 trusted.gpg
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 18 15:17 trusted.gpg.d
```

(though anyhow the permissions on that file now match the permissions
on the files in ./trusted.gpg.d, so I doubt this is a problem(?))

Also FWIW: gpg works fine for *users* on this machine.

Final datapoint: I have another debian-box -- a laptop. On that machine, I just upgraded from jessie to stretch last week, and I *don't* have this problem -- apt-get update doesn't report warnings. (I guess I haven't yet tried to do an "apt-key add" since upgrading to stretch, though...)

Arguably, the warning is not such a big deal, and maybe this will be solved by software upgrades. But it feels broken  to not be able to add package signing keys with apt-key. And: if there is something glitchy about my configuration, I ought to know that...

Thanks for any assistance/advice!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with the official Debian 9.0.0 release yesterday (amd64). Happens on a clean Stretch install and is reproducible.

From what I can tell is that if /etc/apt/sources.list is edited using software-properties-gtk, the first time this is done, it creates a file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg and this file is either corrupt, empty or has bad permissions.

From that point on the presence of that file appears to block keys in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d from being interrogated. It also seems to stop apt-key add from working which would make sense if something is not right with /etc/apt/trusted.gpg (either file issue or software bug).

Deleting /etc/apt/trusted.gpg seems to be the work around and it appears not to be re-created (through further use of software-properties-gtk) after it has been deleted once.

I have posted about this in the debian-user list after spending most of yesterday chasing the NO_PUBKEY errors that seem to be a symptom of having a) the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg file present yet accessible with 0644 permissions. (Initially, I see an error about user '_apt' not being able to read /etc/apt/trusted.gpg which results from the file initially having 0600 permissions.